# Как определить дисплей, на котором отображается окно программы?

Tags: c#, screenshots

К компу подключено несколько дисплеев (два). Необходимо делать скриншот запущенного приложения. Если окно приложения открыто на PrimaryScreen, то все  в порядке. А если нет... Делать скрины всех дисплеев не хочется. Как определить, на каком дисплее открыто окно приложения и, соответственно, фотать только его?

Comment: А если окно растянуто на несколько? :)

Comment: Это будет следующий вопрос :-).

Comment: Прочитал свой вопрос. Написал как-то коряво. Скриншот надо делать из приложения по нажатию соответствующей кнопки. Как из приложения определить на каком дисплее оно открыто?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй вот так определить на каком дисплее открыто окно:

```
Screen screen = Screen.FromControl(this); //this is the Form class
```

Нашел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1121667/4244707)

Касательно скриншота определенного экрана:

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175968/screenshot-from-second-screen) советуют использовать `Screen.AllScreens`, а затеп передать в `CopyFromScreen` `Bounds`  нужного дисплея.